# ComponentArt callback not firing because JavaScript object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, componentart

I'm trying to get this website that runs ComponentArt to run locally. It works on the DEV server but not locally. A number of the call backs aren't working. I set a breakpoint in the server side code, and it's not getting hit because the JavaScript is erroring out that's trying to call it.

The JavaScript error is:

> SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'SaveChanges' is null or undefined, not a Function object
>   File: PopupDataCollectionNoteExternal.aspx.js, Line: 35, Column: 2

The server side code is:

```
<ComponentArtCallbackMethod()> Public Function SaveChanges(ByVal sDrawerID As String, ByVal iDataCollectionRequestID As String, ByVal iNoteID As String, ByVal sNote As String, ByVal iClosed As String, ByVal sResolution As String) As String
...
End Function
```

The JavaScript code is:

```
var sReturn = SaveChanges(sDrawerID,iDataCollectionRequestID, iNoteID, sNote, iClosed, sResolution);
```

Anyone know if there is a configuration item or file it's missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is here:

http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/t/64103.aspx

You are probably running in IIS 7 in integrated mode in the environment where it's not working for you.

This configuration is required for IIS 7 in integrated mode:

```
<system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />

    <httpHandlers>

      <add type="ComponentArt.Web.UI.ScriptHandler,ComponentArt.Web.UI" path="ComponentArtScript.axd" verb="*" />

      <add type="ComponentArt.Web.UI.CallbackHandler,ComponentArt.Web.UI" path="*.aspx" verb="*" />

    </httpHandlers>
        <roleManager enabled="true" />    

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>

     <add name="ComponentArtCallbackHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="ComponentArt.Web.UI.CallbackHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />

      <add name="ComponentArtScriptHandler" type="ComponentArt.Web.UI.ScriptHandler,ComponentArt.Web.UI" path="ComponentArtScript.axd" verb="*" />

    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
```